# Import JAR files to spring using maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I tried to import some JAR files to my maven spring project using maven install plugin.
I placed the JARs in a lib folder in my base directory (where the POM.XML file is) and installed them one by one manually by running mvn install.
My xml looks like:

EDIT:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.keydoxWeb</groupId>
        <artifactId>keydox</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>myPath\codecs.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!-- and so on.. -->
```

Still telling me this error:

"Should use a variable instead of a hard coded path"

Comment: Just define the jar's as dependencies and they will downloaded automatically..nothing else is usually needed...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have over 60 jar's. Do I have to define 60 dependencies or just change the name?

Comment: So where is the problem..Usually you only define a few of them and the others are dependencies of them as well..but in cases you might need to define 60 dependencies which sounds a little bit strange but why not...depends on what you are doing...

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, I imported them using a dependency (see question edit).
But I still can't use the classes?

Comment: Remove scope system and the systemPath...If those dependencies are available from Central you don't need that....

Comment: What do you mean by "available from central"?
I need to install the jars from a folder on C.

Comment: You should start using a repository manager and let your other project deploy the jars into the repository manager...

Comment: Could I d like unigeek said: First install the jars into the repository and use a dependency after to link to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import jars to your local repo, you generally would not have to or want to edit a pom.xml file. Rather there are shell commands that you can use to import the jars to your local maven repo (typically located at ~/.m2). Said commands are described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) -- looks like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Once you do this, you'll also have to bring the dependencies into your projects pom.xml as explicit dependencies. That will look like this:

```
  <dependencies>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try this out tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: What is that dependency for?

I can specify the groupID, etc as I like?

Comment: When trying to install it's telling me: No prefix found for "C".
Guess it's something with my path..

Comment: So, my answer just gave an example. In your pom.xml where I have shown the jackson-databind artifact dependency, you need to substitute whatever group, artifact and version of the jar file you bring in to your local maven repo with mvn install. Repeat a dependency node for each of the jars you did mvn install for.

Comment: Okay, so just like this for example:
install:install-file –Dfile="C:/Program Files/keydox/jkdx/codecs.jar" 
-DgroupId=keydoxWeb -DartifactId=keydoxWebCodec -Dversion=1.0
    but it keeps getting me the error I mentioned.

Comment: I have allergies to both Windows and spaces in a filespec, but I think the error relates to the file path starting with "C:". I might try to run the command from the directory containing the jar to dodge using the "C:" at all. Otherwise you can try "dir /x" to figure out a path with short file names only.. like PROGRA~1/... Just a thought. AFAIK maven is slash-gnostic so forward or backward slashes shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do not have to  import jars manually -  they are installed by maven into local repository.  And eclipse needs to know where this maven repository is.  You may regenerate eclipse project files via

mvn eclipse:eclipse

(or switch to IntelliJ IDEA which opens maven projects natively)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
So I just have to copy put them in the local repository?

Comment: You do not have to - usually.  Maven does it for you while building.